# Android: Inflate Custom View inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-canvas

I have an application that uses a fragment view as part of its layout. Within this fragment, I want to instantiate a Paint Canvas where i can do custom drawing.

The problem is, my app crashes when I go to inflate the fragment with the error `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.example.xxxxx.NeckCanvasOverlay`

I'm not sure what's causing my Paint class not to inflate properly. I know there are special rules about how you use findViewById inside a fragment, but I thought I was adhering to them since i'm calling findViewByid on the fragment's view itself (called "v" in my code).

How can I fix this issue?

**FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.java (Fragment Class)**

```
public class FragmentNeckDisplayMenu extends Fragment {
    private static View v;
    private NeckCanvasOverlay neckHUD;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment_neck_display,container,false);      //ERROR HERE
        NeckCanvasOverlay neckHUD = (NeckCanvasOverlay) v.findViewById(R.id.neckHUD);   //paint test
        ...
        return v;
    }
}
```

**NeckCanvasOverlay.java (Paint Class)**

```
class NeckCanvasOverlay extends View {
    private Paint mPainter;

    public NeckCanvasOverlay(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView(){    //Initializes canvas & paint objects here to save performance
        mPainter = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPainter.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mPainter.setAlpha(128);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(180, 900, 200, mPainter);
    }
}
```

**menu_fragment_neck_display.xml (Fragment's Layout)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/canvas"
    android:background="@drawable/image">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="4">
        !--Custom view for Canvas here -->
        <com.example.xxxxx.NeckCanvasOverlay
            android:id="@+id/neckHUD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/neck_for_menu"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/menuIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="Menu"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Full Stack Trace (Edit: Included full trace)**

```
   08-06 21:47:24.894 26334-26334/com.example.xxxxx E/ACRA: ACRA caught a InflateException for com.example.xxxxx
                                                             android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.example.gu.NeckCanvasOverlay
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                 at com.example.xxxxx.FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.onCreateView(FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.java:32)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(ViewPager.java:733)
                                                                 at com.example.xxxxx.PlayFrets.configMenu(PlayFrets.java:150)
                                                                 at com.example.xxxxx.AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.onPostExecute(AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.java:125)
                                                                 at com.example.xxxxx.AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.onPostExecute(AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.java:9)
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.example.gu.NeckCanvasOverlay
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                 at com.example.xxxxx.FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.onCreateView(FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.java:32) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(ViewPager.java:733) 
                                                                 at com.example.xxxxx.PlayFrets.configMenu(PlayFrets.java:150) 
                                                                 at com.example.xxxxx.AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.onPostExecute(AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.java:125) 
                                                                 at com.example.xxxxx.AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.onPostExecute(AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.java:9) 
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651) 
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180) 
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gu.NeckCanvasOverlay" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.xxxxx-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.xxxxx-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                 at com.example.xxxxx.FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.onCreateView(FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.java:32) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(ViewPager.java:733) 
                                                                 at com.example.xxxxx.PlayFrets.configMenu(PlayFrets.java:150) 
                                                                 at com.example.xxxxx.AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.onPostExecute(AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.java:125) 
                                                                 at com.example.xxxxx.AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.onPostExecute(AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.java:9) 
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651) 
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180) 
                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.gu.NeckCanvasOverlay
                                                                 at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                        ... 33 more
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
08-06 21:47:24.954 26334-27123/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.xxxxx, PID: 26334
                                                   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.example.gu.NeckCanvasOverlay
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                       at com.example.xxxxx.FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.onCreateView(FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.java:32)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(ViewPager.java:733)
                                                       at com.example.xxxxx.PlayFrets.configMenu(PlayFrets.java:150)
                                                       at com.example.xxxxx.AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.onPostExecute(AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.java:125)
                                                       at com.example.xxxxx.AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.onPostExecute(AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.java:9)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.example.gu.NeckCanvasOverlay
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                       at com.example.xxxxx.FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.onCreateView(FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.java:32) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(ViewPager.java:733) 
                                                       at com.example.xxxxx.PlayFrets.configMenu(PlayFrets.java:150) 
                                                       at com.example.xxxxx.AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.onPostExecute(AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.java:125) 
                                                       at com.example.xxxxx.AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.onPostExecute(AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.java:9) 
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651) 
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180) 
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gu.NeckCanvasOverlay" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.xxxxx-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.xxxxx-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                       at com.example.xxxxx.FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.onCreateView(FragmentNeckDisplayMenu.java:32) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(ViewPager.java:733) 
                                                       at com.example.xxxxx.PlayFrets.configMenu(PlayFrets.java:150) 
                                                       at com.example.xxxxx.AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.onPostExecute(AsyncTask_NoteFileLoader.java:125)
```

Comment: Look further on in the stack trace for the root cause. It's probably because you're missing a necessary constructor to inflate your custom `View`. You need a two-argument constructor that takes a `Context` and `AttributeSet`.

Comment: You can see on this link the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599450/how-to-inflate-view-inside-fragment

Comment: You sure you've got the package name correct everywhere? You've got `com.example.xxxxx` in some places, and `com.example.gu` in others. Is that just a search/replace edit error? Double-check that in the layout and class, and try cleaning/rebuilding your project.

Comment: Yes, a search and replace error. Sorry for the confusion. It should be com.example.xxxxx

Comment: Well, it seems that, for some reason, that class doesn't exist in your apk. Are you sure that's correct for that `View` class? I mean, do you maybe have it in a subfolder? What's the `package` at the top of the `NeckCanvasOverlay` class?

Comment: The class doesn't exist. I renamed it from another class to protect IP. I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, but you're getting a `ClassNotFoundException` for `com.example.gu.NeckCanvasOverlay`. Whatever class you've specified in the layout XML does not exist in your apk. Whatever your class and package names are now, you need to make sure that the class is correctly referenced in the XML.

Comment: Good find, this actually was the problem! The class corresponding to the custom View was misnamed in my layout's  XML file. I will accept this as the answer if you post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate problem is a `ClassNotFoundException`. When dealing with custom `View`s in a layout, a common cause for this is an incorrect class name in the layout XML, which seems to have been the issue here. Ensure that the XML tag has the correct, fully-qualified class name for the custom `View` class, which will be the class's `package` from the top of the file, prepended to the class name.

Additionally, `View`s inflated from your layout will be instantiated with a two-argument constructor that takes a `Context` and an `AttributeSet`. Your class definition needs to have at least that constructor to allow inflation, or you'll get a `NoSuchMethodException`. Also, it would make things a little simpler if you'd chain your constructors, if you're just extending `View`. For example:

```
public NeckCanvasOverlay(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public NeckCanvasOverlay(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is safer to include all three constructors for the custom `View`. For example, include the following Constructors for your `NeckCanvasOverlay`.

```
public NeckCanvasOverlay(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
    }

    public NeckCanvasOverlay(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
    }

    public NeckCanvasOverlay(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView();
    }
```

I hope this helps. Give it a try and let me know if you get the same error.