# Why doesn't popBackStack revert to previous fragment with FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an order pager adapter

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OrderPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private FragmentManager fm;

    public OrderPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm = fm;
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
       fm.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

}
```

Methods in my main order activity class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);
    datasource = new Datasource(this);
    categoryFragment = new CategoryFragment();
    productFragment = new ProductFragment();
    detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager2);
    mOrderPagerAdapter = new OrderPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    mOrderPagerAdapter.addFragment(categoryFragment, "category");
    mOrderPagerAdapter.addFragment(productFragment, "product");
    mOrderPagerAdapter.addFragment(detailFragment, "s");
    viewPager.setAdapter(mOrderPagerAdapter);
    }

public void setViewPager(int fragmentNumber) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(fragmentNumber);
}
```

Popbackstack method

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
```

Whenever I click the onBackPressed button the previous fragment isnt loading, why does this happen? I have tried multiple things such as adding to backstack and then committing. But none of the ways seem to be working.

Comment: You are using it inside viewpager? this method will work for you if you have added fragment with fragmentTransaction in any Layout.

Comment: yes im using viewpager. but the method isnt popping the previous fragment

Comment: You need to use **FragmentTransaction** to any container not on ViewPager.

Comment: if you want to get back to previous page then use viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);

Comment: ok i will try doing that

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/12114015/4079010

Comment: ok it works thank you

Comment: can i post this as answer?

Comment: yes you can please do it @RahulKhurana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using it inside viewpager? this method will work for you if you have added fragment with fragmentTransaction in any Layout/Container.

if you want to get back to previous page then use viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);